# How to check if component has child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I am using Jest to test a ReactJS app. How can one test if the view controller has the necessary child components present.

For example, here is an example of the view controllers' render function:

```
// App.js
render: function() {
  var table;
  if (this.state.showResults) {
    table = <Table {...this.state} />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      {table}
  )
}
```

For HTML elements, something like will do:

```
button = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag AppElement, 'button'
```

How can I do the same for the Form or Table components ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Doh ... so the answer is findRenderedComponentWithType.

First, I needed the component class:

```
Form = require('Form.react.js');
```

Then I passed this as argument, like:

```
form = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(AppElement, Form);
```

where, of course

```
AppElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<App />)
```